# Choose languages to translate to/from in FreeSpeak

Tags: freespeak

I installed *FreeSpeak 0.3.0*, a frontend to *online translation engines* but does not let me choose the language to translate *to* and *from*. Prior to FreeSpeak, I tried *YouTranslate* which too didn't work.

Any fix/workarounds to get them work?

(Or any suggestions to alternative GUI front-ends to esp. google's translation engine would be really helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use REQUEST TRANSLATION SUGESTION in the start window it will work using opentrans engine. Freespeak is outdated, there were changes made to google translate and to bing probably

Comment: _OpenTran_ did work... thanks. But is there a way that I can get _google translation engine_ to work?